# WPF - Stop radio button click with message box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a set of dynamically generated radio buttons that when clicked, fill a large amount of textboxes with data. They are bound to a property on the view model that pulls data from a service based on the radio button's label text.

What I want to do is to show a MessageBox when the radio button is clicked, so if the user accidentally (or intentionally) clicks another radio button, I can confirm that's what they wanted to do.

I can catch the click event and display a MessageBox, but the underlying property is changed anyway, triggering the data change. Is there a way that I can stop execution while the MessageBox is shown? Is the Click event the wrong event to use? I'm pretty new to WPF.

Radio button click event:

```
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
  MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Choosing this sample will override any changes you've made. Continue?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
  if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
  {
    radioButton.IsChecked = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

After the second line of the method and before the user's choice is returned is when the property is updated anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by _underlying property is changed anyway, triggering the data change_? I don't understand what is triggered when message box is show.

Comment: The data is loaded and the message box is shown at the same time, not giving the user time to respond

Comment: Do you mean that `RadioButton` is ticked before message box appears?

Comment: Yes, that's why I was wondering if the Click event was the correct event to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Click` event is raised after `RadioButton` is already checked but you can use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event instead and set `Handled` to true

```
<RadioButton ... PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

and in code

```
private void RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Choosing this sample will override any changes you've made. Continue?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        radioButton.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Didn't know about the Preview events, thanks!

Comment: Read more about Routed Events and check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx#how_event_processing_works) link to see the order (and direction) in which routed events are executed